# Netflix Desktop Application will not start, Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, 32-bit, netflix

I got the Netflix Desktop app and did what is said to do from this link
http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html
when I click on Dash Home and click the Netflix Desktop Icon nothing happens. By the way, I am running the 32 Bit version of Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: better to file a bug report in launchpad ppa.